# Typescript: convert string to object

Tags: typescript, object, parsing

I have a problem with an old project, that's not my own code, I'm just responsible for it now.

It is a Sharepoint Webpart written in typescript. We've used the parse method but since thuesday it's not working anymore. I don't know what's exactly the problem and I haven't found a alternative method to replace the parse method.

Does anyone have a idea what could be the problem? Isn't the parse supported anymore for typescript?
Or do you know another method to get an object out of a string? I need the object in the further code.

I get this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined

> lines from the webpart.ts

```
  import * as qs from "simplequerystring";

  let currentHref: string = decodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
  this.currentQuery = qs.parse(currentHref);
```

> loaded interface, this refers to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-query-string@1.3.2/src/simplequerystring.min.js

```
declare module "simplequerystring" {
interface ISimplequerystring {
    parse(str:string, delimiter?:string, eq?:string): any;
    stringify(obj:any, delimiter?:string, eq?:string): string;
}
let simplequerystring: ISimplequerystring;
export = simplequerystring;
}
```

Comment: what you have there is just an interface that describes some of your code(or some library). It has nothing to do with typescript as a language. Having the actual error you get might help

Comment: As @toskv mentioned, there is a more complete sample needed. What's the error?

Comment: thanks; I've edited it

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined` seems like `qs` is undefined. How is the library loaded? Is it added via npm or loaded via script tag inside your application?

Comment: It's loaded in the config.json     
`"simplequerystring": {
      "path": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-query-string@1.3.2/src/simplequerystring.min.js",
      "globalName": "simplequerystring"
    },`

Comment: And it worked until thuesday, no one has touched the webpart

Comment: Can you verify that this file is loaded inside your browsers dev tools (network tab). There should be a request to fetch the file at the CDN. If it is loaded, verify, that the code above isn't executed before hand to avoid possible race-conditions

Comment: It is loaded correctly and it's loaded before the part is executed